# TSP [Nearest Neighbour] - Given The distances Matrix

Tags: python

Mates,

I need to solve a TSP Problem, with the distances info given as follows

[image]

I was trying to solve it by using dictionaries but I can't figure it out:

[image]

**Actually, dont even know how to post code as text here (just got 2 days with Python)

Any advide/help would be more than wellcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you start with this problem?  This requires recursion.  The only way to find the shortest path is to try them all, and there are 480,000,000 paths.

Comment: I mean, I don't need the shortest path, but a feasible one by using the nearest neighbor method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1):

You can do sth like this:

```
import numpy as np

TT= np.array([[0,5,2,13,4],
              [3,0,6,3,14],
              [2,6,0,4,5],
              [2,3,7,0,8],
              [4,2,5,5,0]])

# assume we start in node 0
currentStop = 0
routeList = [0]
for _i in range(len(TT)-1):
    TT[:,currentStop] = 100000 # Set column of visited stop to very large number
    currentStop = np.argmin(TT[currentStop,:])
    routelist.append(currentStop)

print(routelist)
```

Comment: how can we print the distance here?

Answer (score 0):

TSP is an NP-hard problem, which means it's computationally hard to obtain the optimal result. It is possible to try all routes when the data size is small, but in practice we have thousands of nodes (nodes are locations in a TSP problem). Then we would use different searching algorithms to obtain a sub-optimal solution in reasonable time.

Since you are using Python I'd suggest you take a look at [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp). You can take a look at their simple examples to get started. It is written in C with a Python wrapper so it is much faster than pure Python.